# drawing on a panel

Tags: android, android-layout, drawing

**I would like to draw a line on the panel called "maview" after pressing a button "bouton". But my program draws the line on the overall layout, and the button disappears.
Have you an idea? Thank you!
**
my code:

```
package esslineter.pack;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;

public class EsslineterActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.main);  
    }
    public void bouton (View view)
    {   
        maView cv=new maView(this);
        setContentView(cv); cv.invalidate(); 
    }   
    public  class  maView extends View
    {              
            public  maView(Context context)
            {
              super(context);                   
            }
            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
             Paint p = new Paint();
             p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
             p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
             p.setStrokeWidth(3); 
             canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);                    
             canvas.drawLine(0,0, 100, 100, p);                                           
        }                   
    }
}
```

my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bouton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="bouton"
        android:text="draw line" />
    <View class="EsslineterActivity.maView"
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.86" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is bug in your onClick listener:

```
maView cv=new maView(this);
setContentView(cv);
```

You already provide view for Activity in `onCreate` - and here you say that now base view for activity should be `maView`. Just change this piece of code to this:

```
maView cv = (maView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
```

Here you will not create new view but take existing and draw there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but doing exactly what you say, I get a "thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)"...

Comment: 12-16 14:23:28.692: I/Process(652): Sending signal. PID: 652 SIG: 9
12-16 14:24:31.572: D/AndroidRuntime(702): Shutting down VM
12-16 14:24:31.572: W/dalvikvm(702): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-16 14:24:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 14:24:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(702): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-16 14:24:31.682: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setContentView(cv)`, you are changing the entire activity layout so everything disappears and `maView` becomes the only view displayed on the screen.

Instead you can hide your view in your XML layout (`android:visibility="gone"`), and show it when your button is clicked.

```
<View class="EsslineterActivity.maView"
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

And in your code :

```
public void bouton (View view)
{   
    View maView = findViewById(R.id.view1);
    maView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

In general something is wrong if you have to call `setContentView()` multiple times in the same activity. It should be called only once, at the beginning of the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion; I have modified the program accordingly, and I obtain nothing drawn on the panel! Another idea?

Comment: You need to define the height of your view. Try to change the layout_height attribute to a fixed value, like `android:layout_height="20dp"`. If you don't know what the size of your view will be, then you should override the `onMeasure()` method of your custom view (it shouldn't be hard to find some tutorials about it).

Comment: Try to add `maView.setWillNotDraw(false)` at the end of the "bouton" method.